# Como pegar alterações de em um branch/ramo específico de um repositório remoto no GIT?

Tags: git

Criei um novo branch/ramo em minha máquina local. Logo, fiz um `commit` e um `push` para o repositório remoto no BitBucket.

Verifiquei no BitBucket que o novo branch/ramo foi criado com sucesso.

Agora, um outro programador precisa pegar as alterações desse branch/ramo específico pra máquina dele sem comprometer os que ele já tem.

Como faço?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ele deve utilizar o seguinte comando, se ele não tiver o branch na máquina local:

```sh
git checkout --track -b <apelido_do_branch_local> <apelido_do_repositório_remoto>/<apelido_do_branch_remoto>
```

A flag `--track` liga o repositório local com o remoto e a flag `-b` avisa o git que deve ser gerado um novo branch pois o comando `checkout` possui outras funções.

Este comando criará um novo `branch` local igual ao remoto com o apelido `<apelido_do_branch_local>`

Exemplo: meu repositório remoto no GitHub é `https://github.com/luizfilipe/repositorio`
no meu repositório local ele está mapeado para o apelido `origin`, quero trazer o novo branch criado de apelido `branch1`.

O comando a ser executado será:

```
git checkout --track -b branch1local origin/branch1
```

Se ele já possuir o branch local ele deve usar:

```
git pull <apelido_do_repositório_remoto> <apelido_do_branch_local>
```

exemplo:  meu repositório remoto no GitHub é: `https://github.com/luizfilipe/repositorio`
no meu repositório local ele está mapeado para o apelido `origin`, quero trazer atualizar o branch de apelido `branch1`, dentro do `branch1local` eu uso o comando:

```
git pull origin branch1
```

Answer (score 8):

O comando a ser usado é:

```
git checkout --track nome-do-remote/nome-do-branch
```

Este comando criará automáticamente uma branch local com o mesmo nome da remota e o `--track` vai ligar a local com a remota sempre que você fizer um `git push`.

Para saber quais são os seus servidores remotos pode usar o comando:

```
git remote -v
```

Para saber quais são os seus branches remotos pode usar o seguinte comando:

```
git branch --remote --list
```

Comment: Pergunta de leigo: como descubro o [nome-do-remote]?